# Django-filter with ModelChoiceFilter filter displaying {key:value}

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-filter

I'm using ModelChoiceFilter and provided the queryset the following queryset in the filter.py:

> filters.py

```
class PagosFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    semana = django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter(
        queryset=Pagos.objects.order_by('semana').distinct('semana').values('semana'))

    class Meta:
        model = Pagos
        fields = ['semana', ]
```

> in the HTML I'm getting the filter presents the choices like this:

```
{'semana':'2020-W06'}
{'semana':'2020-W05'}
{'semana':'2020-W04'}
```

*instead of:*

```
2020-W06
2020-W05
2020-W04
```

How can I get the values like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem it is that in the queryset I was using 'values', this is what is working now for me:

```
lass PagosFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
semana = django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter(field_name='semana',
                                          queryset=Pagos.objects.order_by('semana').distinct('semana'))

class Meta:
    model = Pagos
    fields = ['semana', ]
```